# PI Camera and Bitbanged GPS -> Fluctuations?

Tags: power, image, gps

I again got a bit of a problem. I am using a Raspberry Pi to BitBang Data out of a UBLOX Gps. I got this working and am receiving the NMEA information as i need it.

Now I added Image acquistion to the loop to save an image with a text overlay showing the received NMEA. I do this every second.

Now the Problem:
With the activated camera and image saving I have acquisition outages at the gps, loosing position information and regaining it again then loosing it again.

My guess is that this is connected to very short power outages at the GPS module as the PiCamera is drawing too much? I not that into electrical engineering stuff...

When I disable the camera the acquisitioning is stable...

I would really appreaciate your help how to solve this issue.

Best regards,

Max

Comment: Sorry, forgive my lousy grammar in a previous comment I deleted, I should have said: "You probably do not have enough of either power or CPU cycles to do all of this - and to check for the the latter try using the `top` command and look at the figures in the top (header) rows."  If you are using a GUI there may be a graph in one part of the taskbar that reports how busy the CPU is as a %age - if that is continuously at 100% that is the same thing - the Pi is trying to do to much at a time and cannot keep up with the GPS data reading task as well as everything else...

Comment: Hej, well I completely forgot about this thread. Solution was much simpler still not less annoying. There was actually no correlation between any power outages of gps and camera usage (as there were no GPS power outages...). It was just making that impression by coincidence. Problem was that I was testing the setup in northern Sweden being seated at a north looking windows of the lab. Basically no visibility to a sufficient number of satellites. So much for being a mid-latitude spoiled European...

Comment: No problem - you are new to Stack Exchange so I should let you know that you are allowed to post and accept a solution to your own question - "move to a location where the GPS device can actually see enough satellites"!  - it gets you reputation and to show that you have researched and solved a problem that others can have as well - everyone (above a certain minimum) can up-vote good answers as well as good questions...